# What do you call someone who cares more about what someone else does than that person themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m writing a story, but I need a word to describe somone in it who cares more about what their kid does than the child themself. Sorry if I messed up any grammar within that question.

Just to clarify, the 1st person cares more about the other’s actions than the other’s well being.

Once again I apologize for any incorrect grammar.

Comment: Your character probably *lives vicariously* through the child.

Comment: If they are more concerned with what the child *does*, then Rob_Ster is correct. If they are more concerned with their child's well-being than their own, then they are *selfless*, *alturistic*, or maybe even *self-sacrificing*.

Comment: I probably should have been more clear with my question than I was, but what I was attempting to ask was this: The father cares about the child’s actions more than the child’s well being. For example, if the child had done something wrong the father would get angry. But if the child had been injured, the father wouldn’t bat an eye. It is my fault for not clarifying.

Comment: That's very, very different isn't it? Such a parent falls somewhere on a broad spectrum between the unmentionable and the unthinkable, at least in polite company. Since this is a literary project, consider casting an allusion toward Thomas Hardy...

Comment: Metaphorically perhaps: 'taskmaster', 'drill sergeant', 'drill instructor'.

Comment: And remember the standard advice: show, don't tell.

Comment: How is this not a request for everyone else to search their dictionaries or thesauruses for you, please?

Comment: and a sample sentence too if you please

Comment: I can't really find the right reference, so perhaps the idiomatic meaning I have is not widespread,  but **vested in** and particularly **inordinately vested in** might be great descriptions that do not spread into 'forcing' or 'manipulating' or 'using' the other.  The 'vested in' would be having and interest in the outcome (as I understand an idiomatic use others might not).  "inordinately", unusually so to excess does not directly say "more" but implies that.  It's not perfect but just sharing it.

Comment: @Tom22 overly invested in the child's image

Comment: @Lambie  you are probably right that the idiom is "invested" with children and "vested" .. while meaning something different,  is an off key note.   Because the parents have invested so much in their children they do have an interest in the outcome.  If the parents stood to benefit from saving costs if the kid qualified for a scholarship they might be said to have  vested financial interest in their childs application?   Certainly I warn people to dig a bit more before taking my example right on.. I didn't make it an "answer"

Answer (score 1):

Robot. 'He treated his child unfeelingly, as if it were a robot, there merely to do his bidding, only criticising when things were wrong, caring not at all for the child's own feelings or needs'

Or Slave. A person with no rights who is owned by another.

'He treated the child as his personal slave...'

Automaton
Doll
Puppet
Made of wood
Heart of stone
Painted doll
Jemima (a kind of doll, the name also references slavery which might be appropriate).
Jemima doll - these originally are black dolls based on 'Aunt Jemima' a slave woman archetype

Pinocchio
The Tin Man

Pinocchio and The Tin Man are stories in which the feeling is missing - but later acquired, that you could possibly reference or plunder from.

Answer (score 1):

First that came to mind:

> [Externalizer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/externalizer)
>
> a person who draws a [locus of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_of_control) from the external world, depending on others as a source of values, ideas, and security.

An example of [externalization](https://psychcentral.com/encyclopedia/externalization/):

> "The patient is extremely argumentative; instead of recognizing this characteristic in herself, however, she complains about the difficult personalities **of others** and views herself as blameless"

Answer (score 1):

> Just to clarify, the 1st person cares more about the other’s actions than the other’s well being.

Where I'm from (southern American English), we often call such a person a **user**: someone who maintains a relationship solely for the purpose of exploitation or parasitism.

But it's common enough usage to be included in *Urban Dictionary*, where it is adequately defined.

Two synonyms of **user**: *gold-digger*, *pimp*

However, **user** may be applied to relationships such as friendships, etc., that do not involve romantic or physical activity. They're habitually parasitic and exploitative, they'll use anyone for any purpose, if they can get away with it.

- They're **users**; they enjoy bragging about their son's achievements, yet constantly criticize and never give him any praise or reward for his efforts.
- She's a **user**; she treats her daughter like a servant, while refusing her even a small allowance or some time to herself.
- He **uses** his son's celebrity to make himself feel famous; he likes the attention.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of [**wicked stepmother**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WickedStepMother) and **[pushy parent](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2931771/Pushy-parents-beware-Children-helicopter-mums-likely-reject-later-life-according-experts.html)**. This last is less an archetype than it is a literal description of something commonly encountered. It isn't a reference to any one character, it is just a very common phrase. You didn't specify parents...

Answer (score 1):

This is a loaded word in many ways, so I hesitate to use this, but have you thought about **narcissist?**

> A person who has an excessive interest in or admiration of themselves.

In this case, they care only how the child's actions reflect upon themselves, and not about the actual child. A narcissist wants to be *seen* as raising a good child, but doesn't actually care whether or not they do.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person who is worried over their child's actions (apparently the ones they disapprove of) even at the cost of the child's well-being is usually called a ***tyrant*** (sometimes suffixed with *of a father/mother*).

ODO:

> **[tyrant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tyrant)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** A person exercising power or control in a cruel, unreasonable, or arbitrary way.
>
> ‘There's this tyrant of a father - whom we've changed to a tyrant of a
>   mother - who's saying marry this guy or die.’
>
> ‘Svensson takes on the persona of Strindberg and talks about his life
>   from a childhood intimidated by a tyrant of a father to the time of
>   his relationships with his three wives.’
>
> ‘After all, she and her husband were not tyrants.’